# How to delete an Encrypted File in Kotlin/ Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am using Kotlin to create and write to an encrypted file stored locally within the app to temporarily store login credentials, On Logout, I want to delete this file.

To create the file I am using the EncryptedFile.Builder method as below;

```
val encryptedFileName = "UserAuthData_.txt"
val mainKey = MasterKey.Builder(applicationContext)
                    .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                    .build()

val encryptedFile = EncryptedFile.Builder(
                    applicationContext,
                    File(applicationContext.applicationInfo.dataDir, encryptedFileName),
                    mainKey,
                    EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
            ).build()
```

I want to delete this file but can't find any way of doing so.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: you found the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delete the file using this -

```
File someFile = new File(encryptedFileName);
someFile.delete();
```